# DB Installation Issue: Binary files folder (bin) is missing in downloaded zip for MongoDB (Windows 64-bit)

Tags: mongodb, failed-installation, database-installation

I downloaded the MongoDB for Windows 64-bit from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads.
File name: mongodb-src-r3.0.3.zip

However, the zip folder doesn't have a bin folder & no .exe files to use for installation (as given in the installation steps).

The below commands say that I use Windows 7 64-bit architecture.
wmic os get caption
wmic os get osarchitecture

Even tried using the .msi (Installation Package) given in the same downloads page. It doesn't give any error. But still the bin folder is not created to test MongoDB (mongod.exe).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Umm. "src" means it the source code and not a binary installation. Read the instructions here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/. There is an [MSI package](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.0.3-signed.msi?_ga=1.237387584.1796851287.1433258700) that makes this all simple

Comment: @user3561036: Thank you. I really missed to notice the 'src' part. Yet, not sure only 64-bit installation should have this. Other (32-bit/64-bit Legacy) packages are fine. On the MSI package, I already tried (interactive one) & I'd mentioned the same above. However, I just tried the automated mode (via shell) & it was successful. www.mongolab.com seems to be more simple (0.5 GB free).

Comment: You can find recent package here. https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community?jmp=docs

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same problem as @ArcherGilly told to install again and select the custom options and by doing this finally I found the ***bin*** folder with other txt file like license

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0` -> Previously there were only two folders

- data
- log

and Now along with the above two folders, there is bin folder along with 4 more files

- LICENSE-Community.txt
- MPL-2
- README
- THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
- THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.gotools

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but once I used the .msi installer and selected 'custom', instead of 'complete', it installed the /bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
It could be because you changed the installation directory to another drive where the windows folder isn't.

So if this your case, simply find the bin folder in the C: drive.

Comment: Yeah I did change the directory from C to D,,Thanks I will check

Comment: I checked and this was the case,,It worked for me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the installation, I used the installer and chose the make changes option without making really any changes. After the process was finished I found the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the msi and installation process. I found the bin folder but there is no mongo.exe file in that folder.

But when I run the path enclosed in " \mongo.exe" in command prompt, the mongo db is running.

Answer (score 0):

while using .msi installer please select 'custom', instead of 'complete', it will create the bin folder at \Installation_Dir\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\

Thanks

Comment: Are you thanking someone? Or is it a greeting like "Thanks for reading"?